# Will it cost money to upload a phone application?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

Similar to how Apple and Microsoft require you to buy a developer 'subscription' for $99. The google play costs $25, does Ubuntu have a similar cost or is it free?

Comment: We are talking about commercial applications here, not open-source applications, right? Can you edit your question to reflect that?

Comment: if you are asking about ubuntu touch app, there is no information on it yet.

Answer (score 6):

The important part of the answer can be found here:

http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/commercial-software-faqs/

For commercial software you have to register, but:

"*The Ubuntu Application Developer programme is free of charge, there are no fees to join.*"

Of course if you want to sell your Apps, there will be a percentage of charge:

"*The application publisher chooses a global price to sell their application for. For each sale Canonical retains a transaction fee of 20% after tax. If you sell an application for 10.00 USD, then the fee will be 2.00 USD.*"

```
Apple:     99$/year   30% commission on revenues
Google:    25$ once   30% commission on revenues
Microsoft: 0-99$/year 30% commission on revenues
Ubuntu:    0$         20% commission on revenues
```

[(more details at Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_software_distribution_platforms)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Ubuntu one but it goes through a review process
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppReviewBoard/Submissions

Or you can use Launchpad and you run your own repository that other users must add to the Ubuntu software center

http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/ppa/

It's free